# Enable clipboard in automated tests with Protractor and webdriver

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, clipboard

I want to test with Protractor an Angular application that accesses the system clipboard using the [clipboard api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard). The problem is that, when executing the test, the Chromium browser asks the user for permission to access the clipboard. I can't close this box from the test, because this is not a DOM element nor an alert window, and it seems not to be any way to access it from Protractor.

[clipboard permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXoIc.png)

I have tried to automatically give permission in Chrome, in protractor setup. First, I looked for a [command line switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) that do it, but it seems not to exist.

Then I found a way that apparently works, but I don't know if its stable: to set an "exception" in Chrome user profile, using the [Capabilities of the chrome driver of webdriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities). Basically, I add the following lines of my protractor config file:

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'prefs': {
        'profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard': {
          'http://localhost:8000,*': {'last_modified': Date.now(), 'setting': 1}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have found the value by looking inside `Default/Preferences` file inside my Chrome profile.

It now works for me, but I don't want to use undocumented features, since they can change anytime without notice. Do you know a better way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Somehow this does not work on my side. Can you give more details about your setup, versions or anything else that could have a role here? I would use it in my test setup. Did a lot of googling but could not find a way to solve the problem. In this case I would totally go with it, because you asked about undocumented features, if there is no other way - better than skipping the test at all.

Comment: update: I had to set the value to 1 (setting: 1) to prevent the permission popup, but this does not work in headless mode - according to [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925) headless chrome ignores all the prefs set via chromeOptions, it is not supported.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You are true, have to set the value to 1, i have corrected it.

My tests were in normal mode, i have tried to run it in headless mode and the test crashes, not sure if it's because of this or for other readon, I'll need to investigate a bit more.

I'm using protractor 5.4, selenium-webdriver 3.0 and the latest crhome driver, on npm 5.6.

Comment: @hirunatan Can you share how you implemented this test?

Comment: I do not check the clipboard in the test. Simply I perform the 'copy' operation, then 'paste' in other place, and check the result state of the data.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking to do something similar with C#, I have adapted the code as such:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
var clipboardException = new Dictionary<string, object> {
  {"[*.]myurl.com,*", 
    new Dictionary<string, object> {
      {"last_modified", DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()}, 
      {"setting", 1}
    }
  }
};          
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.content_settings.exceptions.clipboard", clipboardException);
```

Comment: Thank you, Max, for the contribution.

Only as a detail, could you please format a little your code, to avoid such long lines? It would improve readability, and it will become perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal behat.yml here is how i did it

```
prefs:
  profile:
    content_settings:
      exceptions:
        clipboard:
          'https://place.yoursite.here,*':
            last_modified: '13312479654276119'
            setting: 1
            expiration: "0"
```